# Spring Data Implementing a CreateIfDoesntExist repository method, concurrency issues

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

The application will receive a number of REST calls that will cause the creation of a number of `item` Entities. A number of these entities will share a ID that identifies the particular `import` these object are being created as part of. I need each `item`, as part of its creation, to check whether the `import` entity already exists, if not it should create it.

I'm trying to implement a "Create If Doesnt Exist" method on the `import` repository, but having concurrency issues. The first `item` calls the method, which checks for the existence of the `import`. It returns 0 results, so calls `Save()`. However when a second `item` calls this repository method again, the `import` still hasnt been created. It therefore gets 0 results back from the find, and attempts to create the `import` again, which fails because of a unique key constraint on the database table.

ImportRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface ImportRepository extends 
ImportRepositoryCustom{

    List<Import> findByReference(String reference);

}
```

ImportRepositoryCustom.java

```
@Repository
public interface ImportRepositoryCustom {
    void saveIfNotExists(Import import);
}
```

ImportRepositoryImpl.java

```
@Repository
public class ImportRepositoryImpl implements 
ImportRepositoryCustom{

    @Autowired
    ImportRepository importRepository;

    public void saveIfNotExists(Import import){

        if (importRepository.findByReference(import.getReference()).size() == 0){        
            importEventRepository.save(import);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to ensure that the `save()` is carried out as part of the same transaction, so as to avoid this race condition?

Spring Boot 1.5.7

Comment: And why won't you throw an exception? You now basically silently ignore an erroneous situation. And the default save already checks for this (it does a save or an update depending on if it exists or not).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your comment. Save is attempting to insert the same `import` twice, this is the point of my post. What exception should I be throwing here, and how would that help address the issue?

Comment: I'm questioning what you are doing here, it looks overly complex and you basically can have a situation that the calling code might think something got saves (no exception is thrown) where it actually isn't.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps my question wasn't clear. In theory, if `saveIfNotExists()` is called and an `import` is not created, thats because it already exists, thats not a problem, I don't see why an exception needs to be thrown in that case.

Comment: Then don't do this check and just catch the exception? Why make it more complex then that.

Comment: Because the Exception isnt been passed back up, I can't catch it here. I've already tried catching the exception it doesnt work, it shouldnt be throwing the exception anyway, the findByReference check beforehand should return the existing `import` but its not been created yet. Thats the focus of my question.

Comment: It will throw an exception if you do `saveAndFlush` else it will only throw an exception AFTER the `@Transactional` also what isn't committed yet won't be detected so no it will not be found if the other tx didn't commit anything yet.

Comment: You probably want to mark saveIfNotExists as
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) 
so that the import will be visible (commited) by other sessions as soon as possible.  And then you probably want to synchronize the saveIfNotExists method so that you serialize the lookup and creation if not found - that should fix the concurrency issue.  Note that synchronized is only going to work for a single-server deployment model, but if each import is handled by a single server it should be good enough.

Comment: Sceaj, this worked perfectly, if you post as an answer I'll accept. Thanks.